# How do I write a Bash script that will ask users to define a variable?

Tags: shell-script, prompt, variable

I am presently modifying [this shell script](https://github.com/elasticdog/packer-arch/raw/master/install-virtualbox.sh) to turn it into a shell script for installing Arch Linux, with custom username(s), password(s), *etc.* At the moment I am wondering what I need to do in order to get this script to prompt users for a value for the `FQDN` variable (which is essentially the hostname for the Arch Linux machine) and set this variable to whatever value the user types in. If you are unclear as to what I mean take the example of the `passwd` command and how it prompts users to set the password for the target account, via this sort of prompt:

```
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password:
```

I would like this shell script to prompt users with:

```
Enter hostname:
```

To set their PC's hostname. Then users enter their desired hostname and it is used as the value for the `FQDN` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash`, you can use the `read` function to request input from a user and store it in a variable. You should be careful using this to read in passwords. A good primer on this builtin can be found at http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html#sect_08_02_01